# Run controller in background Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, message-queue, bulk-actions

How can I run controller in background? I read about Message Queues and Deferred Actions, but it is hard for me to understand how it works and which should I use.

For now it is implemented like this:
Mass Action Button on Product Listing -> Controller -> Model -> Success (or Error) message.

I would like the information to be displayed after pressing the button that the synchronization is in progress, and when it is over - that it has finished (a message on screen or in the logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can study the code from Magento, here in the Cart Price rule section, under Manage Coupon Codes, when you press Generate, it will send the request to the queue

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do you know in which module is code to generate coupons?

Comment: It's Magento Sales Rule